# searching in a list for a record with specific fields and ignoring the rest

Tags: erlang

I have a record defined as:

```
1> rd(fact, {a,b,c}).
fact
```

I create three records and put them in a list

```
2> F1 = #fact{a=1,b=1,c=1}.
#fact{a = 1,b = 1,c = 1}
(3> F2 = #fact{a=2,b=2,c=2}.
#fact{a = 2,b = 2,c = 2}
3> F3 = #fact{a=3,b=3,c=3}.
#fact{a = 3,b = 3,c = 3}
4> L = [F1,F2,F3].
[#fact{a = 1,b = 1,c = 1},
 #fact{a = 2,b = 2,c = 2},
 #fact{a = 3,b = 3,c = 3}]
```

Now, I want to check if the list contains a record in which 'a' is 1 and I don't care for the rest of the fields

```
(dilbert@Martin-PC)21> lists:member(#fact{a=1}, L).
false
(dilbert@Martin-PC)23> lists:member(#fact{a=1,b=1,c=1}, L).
true
```

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Records are pure syntactic sugar. When you don't specify the values of the other fields in a record declaration the atom 'undefined' is used. Therefore your search is for:

```
#fact{a=1, b='undefined', c='undefined'}
```

... which of course doesn't exist.

Try this instead:

```
lists:any(fun(#fact{a=A}) -> A =:= 1 end, L).
```

Comment: this looks great because i can make the comparison on more than one field which i couldn't do with lists:keyfind/2. also lists:any/2 will break the look when a match is found which the list comprehension wouldn't do.

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use keyfind.

```
lists:keyfind(1, #fact.a, L).
```

Answer (score 3):

Or list comprehension:

```
OneList = [E || E <- L, E#fact.a =:= 1]
```